# Placing a textview on top of imageview in android

Tags: android, textview, android-imageview

- I have a `listview`, that has a single `imageview` which is
  scrollable vertically
- I am trying to place a `textview` on top of `Imageview`
- Both the views must be visible

---

1. Is it possible ?
2. If yes, How to do it programmatically ?
3. What changes should i need to make ?

---

list_view_item_for_images.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It gives a output like below

[image]

How to do something like below

[image]

note :: Dish 1 & 2 are textviews

Comment: add text view over the ImageView

Comment: can you show it by editing xml as answer .... textview must be visible on top of image view

Comment: the secret is **RelativeLayout**.  (Rather than LinearLayout, etc)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

This should give you the required layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/flag"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Play with the `android:layout_marginTop="20dp"` to see which one suits you better. Use the id `textview` to dynamically set the `android:text` value.

Since a RelativeLayout stacks its children, defining the TextView after ImageView puts it 'over' the ImageView.

**NOTE:** Similar results can be obtained using a `FrameLayout` as the parent, along with the efficiency gain over using any other android container. Thanks to `Igor Ganapolsky`(see comment below) for pointing out that this answer needs an update.

Comment: If you want to align `<TextView>` vertically, remove `android:layout_alignParentTop`, `android:layout_marginTop`, and add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to `<TextView>`.

Comment: @LeeHanKyeol Sure. As an aside, if only `center_vertical` alignment is needed, `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` is sufficient.

Comment: Why is RelativeLayout preferred to FrameLayout here?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I based my answer on the details(layout) given in the question. I save `RelativeLayout` for the rare occasions where its the perfect fit - it's not here unless the layout given is a simplified version of the actual one. Plus, `FrameLayout` isn't as featureless as its made out to be. Thanks, the answer has been edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src=//source of image />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ImageViewText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/ImageView"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/ImageView"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/ImageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/ImageView"
    android:text=//u r text here
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Hope this could help you.

Comment: You must make sure to put the `ImageView` on top of the `TextView`

Answer (score 8):

you can use [framelayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) to achieve this.

how to use framelayout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ImageView 
   android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:scaleType="fitCenter"
   android:layout_height="250px"
   android:layout_width="250px"/>

   <TextView
   android:text="Frame Demo"
   android:textSize="30px"
   android:textStyle="bold"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

ref: [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_frame_layout.htm)

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned in OP, you need to overlay `Text` on `ImageView` programmatically way. You can get `ImageView` drawable and write on it with the help of putting it on `Canvas` and `Paint`.

```
 private BitmapDrawable writeTextOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text) 
 {
 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
 Typeface tf = Typeface.create("Helvetica", Typeface.BOLD);
 Paint paint = new Paint();
 paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
 paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
 paint.setTypeface(tf);
 paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
 paint.setTextSize(11);
 Rect textRect = new Rect();
 paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), textRect);
 Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
 canvas.drawText(text, xPos, yPos, paint);
 return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bm);
 }
```

Comment: I want to place a text on the imageview and want the freedom to drag and drop on it where ever i want to. Something similar done in "Phonto" application.

Answer (score 0):

just drag and drop the TextView over ImageView in eclipse

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="114dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bluehills" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="85dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this the output the above xml[image]

Comment: can we create out a bit map out of this?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this too. I use just framelayout.

```
 <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cover"
                android:gravity="bottom">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Hello !"
                    android:id="@+id/welcomeTV"
                    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom" />
            </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure to put the `ImageView` over the `TextView` in the `FrameLayout`. That's simple but I hope it helps somebody. :)