# Center TextView over ImageView

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to create buttons for KitKat similar to that of Android L Fab buttons.  The problem I am having is that for some of it, I cannot get the text to center on the button.

The hyphen shows up near the bottom of the circle.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/subtract_circle"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/add_circle"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="-"
                android:id="@+id/tvMinus"
                android:textSize="100dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/subtract_circle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/subtract_circle"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/subtract_circle"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/subtract_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="-50dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

If I am doing the +, that shows up fine.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/add_circle"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/add_circle"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="+"
                android:id="@+id/tvAdd"
                android:textSize="70dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/add_circle"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/add_circle"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/add_circle"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/add_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

I'm sure it has something to do with the font, but is anyone aware of a way I could programmatically fix this or fix it in the xml?

Thanks

Comment: Refer to this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/19065295/2637961

Comment: I have the font showing above the ImageView which is working ok.  I have messed with a layout margin and that doesnt seem to change anything.  I have also added it dynamically but still no change, the - is at the bottom of the circle :(

Comment: If you're making buttons, why not use a button? You can use a custom background selector with your circle images.

Comment: Yes I can do that.  I think I may have to go that route and use an image instead of text as the background.