# Add TextView over ImageView (Android)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview

i am displaying full screen image in ImageView and i am trying to add TextView in center of screen over ImageView but TextView is not showing.

i tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash_imageview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:padding="12dip"
        android:text="SomeText"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: use RelativeLayout or FrameLayout instead of Linear

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065232/placing-a-textview-on-top-of-imageview-in-android

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use `FrameLayout`, `AbsoluteLayout` (deprecated) or `RelativeLayout` (most common of these). An example of `RelativeLayout`, for centering is used `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`, set for both childs

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash_imageview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:padding="12dip"
        android:text="SomeText"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Drawing `View`s is in the same order as in XML, so `ImageView` will be drawn first and then `TextView` over it

Another approach would be to use `FrameLayout` with `android:gravity="center"` attr (nothing needed for childs)

Also remeber and read about `android:elevation` and `android:translationZ` XML attributes, which may reorder drawing, and also `view.bringToFront()` method

Answer (score 3):

Try This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/myImage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="I am TextView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splash_imageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:background="#AA000000"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="12dip"
        android:text="SomeText"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Exactly the thing i wanted, much better than FrameLayout

Answer (score 2):

There is a new attribute **android:elevation** you can use for this problem.
but note that is used in API 21 or higher.

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/welcome_tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:elevation="100dp"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

`<FrameLayout ...>` draws its children one on top of another.

Note that you can specify background as fully transparent.

Answer (score 0):

In Relative Layout you can also use the following properties in a TextView in order to make it appear on top of an ImageView:

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1" 
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
```