# How to set text over multiple images which is inside one LinearLayout?

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

I want to put some text over image. Can someone please help me with this?

I have six rectangular box and I want to put some text on each box. I have used `ImageView` to make the rectangles.

Please find the below **mainactivity.xml** code :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.example.vimal.edkul.StudentProfile">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout1">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/title">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/pic13" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="User Profile"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_overflow" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout1"
        android:padding="30dp">
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="130dp">
            <View
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="Some text" />
        </FrameLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_width="130dp">
            <View
                android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:id="@+id/view2"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="Some text" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

rectangle.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <corners android:radius="12px"/>
    <stroke  android:width="2dip" android:color="#000000"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Use framelayout instead of linearlayout

Comment: @payaltuteja thanks for the reply .I am new to android if I use framelayout so How can I put text over an image can give me a example please that will help me to understand better.

Comment: Do you want to add text into images' bitmaps? Or placing text into standard TextViews and placing of that TextViews in front of ImageViews will be enough?

Comment: @ArtemMostyaev I want to place some text over image not in bitmaps.It is like a box title something like that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065232/placing-a-textview-on-top-of-imageview-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following part of the layout instead of every `ImageView`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_width="100dp" >

    <View
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:id="@+id/buttonVote"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" />

    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textStatusMessage"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Some text" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**EDIT**

You can change background in `rectangle.xml`. For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
    <corners android:radius="12px" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

That xml [looks that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7ydZ.jpg) for me.

You can even delete `FrameLayout` and `View` and set backgound for the TextView:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"/>
```

P.S. To show the simple image you don't need to use `ImageView`, simple `View` with the background is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the help.It worked but I am not able to set background color.I have mention some color in rectangle.xml in drawable folder.But it doesn't apper in screen.

Comment: Maybe you need to change View to ImageView with `src` parameter. But this looks strange. Can you post your `rectangle.xml` into your question body? And, if you can, please update an entire xml, how did you changed it?

Comment: I have update my code with new activity.xml and rectangle.xml .