# how to add text view inside imageview

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android. I created one grid view with image view. I am trying to add two text view overlay to the image view.

Hellogridview.java

```
public class HelloGridView extends AppCompatActivity {
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(350, 350));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    return imageView;
}

// references to our images
private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
        R.drawable.greenbox,R.drawable.greenbox,R.drawable.greenbox
};
```

I want to display two text views inside the image view.The text will fetch from array.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use FrameLayout

Comment: can u give me an example ?

Comment: Tons of examples out there. Use google...Come back when you stuck.

Comment: My doubt is it possible to add grid layout in frame layout?

Comment: Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065232/placing-a-textview-on-top-of-imageview-in-android) that might help you.
Thanks.