# How add title in imageview?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

i have this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTLjQ.png)

But i wanna:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whe0N.png)

My XML:

```html
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="380dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:paddingBottom="-10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/dog_full"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="#222"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textColor="#222"
            android:textSize="18dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

How i can did this? Thank you!

Could you show us how to make this markup? Could you show us how to make this markup?

Comment: use align bottom imstead of layout below. as simple as that

Answer (score 1):

Since your title is already in a RelativeLayout and it is below the thumbnail, you can add a negative marginTop to the title. Something like:

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:marginTop="-30dp"
        android:textColor="#222"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

You can adjust the dp as needed.

Comment: text sizes are font dependant. hence bad way to implement. align bottom is perfect solution.

Comment: frame layout can also be used

Comment: @vm345 frame layout is good if your view contains only text and image, but since his layout also has descriptiom at bottom, frame layout will cause unnecessary nesting increasing the cost of fimdviewbyod

Comment: @MohammedAtif that's true. Good catch! align bottom without layout_below works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Just use android:layout_alignBottom

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/card_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/card_margin">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/cafe_img"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large_plus"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/img_card"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBackground"
            android:background="@color/transparentColor"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using relative layout https://stackoverflow.com/a/19065295/7505436 or using frame layout http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_frame_layout.htm