# Place a textView in the middle of imageView programatically android

Tags: java, android

I have an ImageView and a TextView declared programatically(not in any xml).

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
TextView txt = new TextView(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams coordinates = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

img.setLayoutParams(coordinates);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
txt.setText("a");
```

How could I place the text in the middle of the imageview ? I need that "a" to be always in the middle of imageView.

Comment: Take a look at this answer, might be of help https://stackoverflow.com/a/19065295/5193533

Comment: what do you mean by middle? on top of imageview?

Comment: think of that you have a circle image view. The text should be in the centre  of that circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should just have an text view and use image as a background:

```
textView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img);
```

Comment: Yup, you're right. That centred my text perfectly in the middle of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Using Pragmatically  you can set it

```
   RelativeLayout relativeLayout=new RelativeLayout(context);
//set Relative Layout Parameter using 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.MATCH_PARENT,RelativeLayout.MATCH_PARENT);
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);
```

First create ImageView

```
ImageView imageView=new ImageView(context);
relativeLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Then set text view on it

```
TextView textView=new TextView(context);
relativeLayout.addView(textView);
```

Answer (score 1):

To centralize the text programmatically, you just need to use **gravity**

```
ImageView img = new ImageView(this);
TextView txt = new TextView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams coordinates = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

img.setLayoutParams(coordinates);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
txt.setText("a");
txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

To show it in the middle of ImageView, you can further extend ImageView width to MATCH_PARENT so that the text will always appear in the middle of Imageview