# Android: How to fix the image that is overlapping my text?

Tags: android, xml

How do I fix this error. Basically, the image is overlapping the text.
Can we fix this in XML ?

Here's the code (Of course, it's incomplete).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFCC0000"
    >

    <TextView
        android:background="#55000000"
        android:id="@+id/centerButton"
        android:text="RELATIVE LAYOUT RULES!"
        android:textSize="33dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/centerButton"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="PUSH ME!"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4" />

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/Cat"
        android:layout_above="@+id/centerButton"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="39dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

SCREENSHOT OF ERROR:
[image: Error]

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065232/placing-a-textview-on-top-of-imageview-in-android

Comment: @Xedon can you share @drawable/Cat image

Comment: looks like your textview is behind the imageview. Try putting the textview codes below the imageview in the xml. which will bring the textview to the front of the image

Comment: I've tried the layout you've shared. It works. Is it not your preview which needs to be refreshed? How is it displayed on an actual device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order TextView -> ImageView to ImageView -> TextView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFCC0000"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/Cat"
        android:layout_above="@+id/centerButton"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="39dp" />


    <TextView
        android:background="#55000000"
        android:id="@+id/centerButton"
        android:text="RELATIVE LAYOUT RULES!"
        android:textSize="33dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_margin="40dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/centerButton"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="PUSH ME!"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button4" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're exactly looking for but I can think of two quick solutions:

First off, you need to change the `TextView`'s `id` tag to something else, it currently has the same `id` as your `Button` which is not good. I think you mean `centerText`.

**1. You want the `TextView` to appear over the `ImageView`**

To achieve that you actually just need to move the `TextView` XML element below the `ImageView` element. Because Views are "layered" in top to bottom order in terms of the XML layout, this will place the `TextView` on top of the `ImageView`.

**2. You want the `ImageView` to simply not overlap the `TextView`**

You could change `android:layout_above="@+id/centerButton"` to `android:layout_above="@+id/centerText"` where `centerText` is your `TextView` with the corrected `id` tag of course.

Hopefully that solves your problem! If not, please be a bit more specific about what you're looking to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

Android draw the layout in other of the other from top to bottom in XML file. If you want your TextView draw above, you need to bring it to the bottom.